# Unable to display drop down values using Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 5 and working on a tutorial. Got struck with displaying drop down values in form. component.html shown below does not display drop down values. Here is what I tried. Any help to resolve this error is highly appreciated.

model.ts:

```
export class State {

    constructor(public code: number, public description: string) { }
  }
```

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { State } from '../shared/prediction-input.model';

@Injectable()
export class GenericService {
   getStates(): State[] {
      let states = [
         new State(1, 'CA'),
         new State(2 , 'TX'),
         new State(3 , 'IL'),
         new State(4 , 'WI')
      ]  
      return states;      
   }


}
```

component.html:

```
Select Vehicle Owner State: 



 <select name="State" [(ngModel)]="State" >
                            <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Choose Vehicle owner State</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let s1 of allStates" [ngValue]="s1.code">
                                {{ s1.code }}
                              </option>


                    </select>
```

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.allStates = this.genericService.getStates();
    console.log("State Code : " + this.allStates[0].code);
    console.log("Description Code : " + this.allStates[0].description);
  }
```

Comment: ` [(ngModel)]="State" ` -> here you're trying to bind the value of selected option to `State` (class). That makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

Step 1: Class State:

```
export class State{
   constructor(public code: number, public description: string) {}
}
```

Step 2: in service.ts

```
export class Service {
      private state: State[] = [
         new State(1, 'CA'),
         new State(2 , 'TX'),
         new State(3 , 'IL'),
         new State(4 , 'WI')
       ];
      constructor() { }

      getData() {
        return this.state;
      }
    }
```

Step 3: In component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  public state: State[] = [];
  constructor(public service: Service) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
        this.state = this.service.getData();
    }
 }
```

Step 4: Component html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of state;let i = index">
    {{item.code}}
    {{item.description}}
</div>
```

or:

```
<select name="State">
 <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Choose Vehicle owner State</option>
 <option *ngFor="let item of state;let i = index" >
   {{item.code}}
   {{item.description}}
  </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the issue you are facing but here is a working stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-dm5bd2?file=app/app.module.ts

1. Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { State } from './State';

@Injectable()
export class GenericService {
   getStates(): State[] {
      let states = [
         new State(1, 'CA'),
         new State(2 , 'TX'),
         new State(3 , 'IL'),
         new State(4 , 'WI')
      ]  
      return states;      
   }
}
```

2. Model

```js
export class State {
    constructor(public code: number, public description: string) { }
  }
```

3. Component Template

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
 <select name="State" [(ngModel)]="State">
                            <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Choose Vehicle owner State</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let s1 of allStates" [ngValue]="s1.code">
                                {{ s1.code }}
                              </option>


                    </select>
</p>
```

4. Component Class

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GenericService } from './GenericService';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  public allStates: any[] = [];
  public State: any;

  constructor(private genericService: GenericService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allStates = this.genericService.getStates();
    console.log("State Code : " + this.allStates[0].code);
    console.log("Description Code : " + this.allStates[0].description);
  }
}
```

5. App Module: You have to register the GenericService in the providers.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { GenericService } from './GenericService';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers:[GenericService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi binDebug - It worked for me now when I remove the <form> tag in template and loading the drop down as separate. I need to debug why this is not able to work within the form tag.

Comment: Just added the form tag in the stackblitz link above. This one - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-dm5bd2?file=app%2Fapp.component.html.  It is working. Have you imported the formsmodule in AppModule?